# How to create a temporary table in SSIS with an identity column and a dynamic seed value

Tags: ssis

When an SSIS tasks runs, I want to create a temporary table with an identity column. However the seed for this column should start with a value = Select max(columnname_from_another_table) + 1.

I know SQL but not SSIS. One method I know is create the table and then issue something like 'DBCC CHECKIDENT('TempTable', RESEED, @TheCalculatedSeedValue) but I am not sure how to put all this together in SSIS.

Answer (score 2):

SSIS has what are called SQL Tasks. This enables you to execute any T-SQL you want. You can have as many SQL Tasks as you want in an SSIS package. This should do what you want.

Comment: Correct-just add that tsql to your SQL Tasks or create a sp and call that using your SQL Task.